# Во время отправки файла в метод POST параметр IFormFile равен null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

Я пытаюсь реализовать отправку файла на сервер. У меня есть форма на странице:

```
<form name="addForm" asp-action="PostMusic" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label for="songName">Song name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="songName" />
    <label for="artistName">Artist name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="artistName" />
    <label for="albumName">Album name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="albumName" />
    <input type="file" name="soundFile" id="soundFile" value="Music file"/>
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" value="Image file"/>
    <label for="videoLink">Video link (YouTube): </label>
    <input type="url" name="videoLink" />
    <label for="categories">Category: </label>
    <select name="categories" id="categorySelect">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="autorSongs">Author Song</option>
        <option value="blues">Blues</option>
        <option value="jass">Jass</option>
        <option value="country">Country</option>
        <option value="classic">Classic</option>
        <option value="latinAmerican">Latin American</option>
        <option value="metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        <option value="reggi">Reggi</option>
        <option value="rhytmNBlues">Rhytm-n-Blues</option>
        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
        <option value="rap">Rap</option>
        <option value="folk">Folk</option>
        <option value="hipHop">Hip-Hop</option>
        <option value="electroMusic">Electro</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="addMusicBtn" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

файл .js, в котором я формирую данные

```
var soundFileName = $('#soundFile').get(0).files[0].name;
    var soundFile = $('#soundFile').get(0).files[0];
    var soundFormData = new FormData();
    soundFormData.append(soundFileName, soundFile);
await fetch("../App/music/sound", { method: 'POST', body: soundFormData });
```

И сам метод POST в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost("sound")]
    public void PostMusic([FromForm(Name ="addForm")]IFormFile sound)
    {
        string path = "../Musics";
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sound.FileName);
        using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
        {
            sound.CopyTo(stream);
        }
    }
```

При отправке файла, в самом JS файл формируется, но в метод PostMusic передается null (IFormFile sound равен null). Спасибо заранее за любую помощь

Comment: посмотри в отладке, приходит ли в форме что-нибудь в Request

Comment: Имеете ввиду в formData?

Comment: На сервере есть свойство `Request` - посмотри что в нем приходит и в каких полях

Comment: Посмотрел, в свойстве Request, в свойстве Body поля Length и Position выкидывают исключения System.NotSupportedException, а также ReadTimeOut и WriteTimeOut вызываются исключения System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: У тебя [не совпадает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#match-name-attribute-value-to-parameter-name-of-post-method) имя параметра и имя отправляемого поля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что это заработало [имя поля в FormData должно совпадать с именем параметра](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#match-name-attribute-value-to-parameter-name-of-post-method)

Имя поля в FormData задается первым параметром, при вызове метода `append`

```
soundFormData.append(soundFileName, soundFile);
```

В данном случае, в качестве имя поля устанавливается имя файла - это неверно, если не подразумевается, что загружать можно только файл с определенным именем.

Для передачи имени файла используется [третий параметр](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Таким образом, вызов должен был выглядеть так:

```
soundFormData.append('sound', soundFile, soundFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

в параметрах имя sound, в FormData - soundFile + свойство Name у FromForm можно удалить мне кажется

Comment: Думаю нет, так как оно используется у меня в методе Append